# Textarea default value not coming when keeping onchange attribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have two components parent and child,in child i have the text area, which onchange will reset my initial value.
On keeping onchange attribute in the textarea , the default value is being removed
Initially it should show default value, upon changing it should change the text.

**Parent**

```js
const Main = () => {

    const notes = [
        {id:1,
         title:"What is React? ",
        content:"React is a JavaScript library that aims to simplify development of visual interfaces.",
        // date:"28/04/2023"
        },
        {
         id:2,
         title:"What is Java?",
         content:"Java is a most popular, object-oriented, widely used programming language and platform that is utilized for Android development, web development, artificial intelligence, cloud applications, and much more.",
        //  date:"28/04/2023"
        }
    ]
    const [mynote, setNote] = useState(notes);
    const [isActive,setisActive] = useState([]);
  
    const handleClick = (id) =>{
       setisActive(id);
    }

    const pullcontent = (id,plnote) =>{
      console.log("pull Content for->"+id+"..."+plnote);
      setNote(mynote.map(obj =>{
        if( obj['id'] === parseInt(id)){
          return {...obj,content:plnote}
        }else{
          return obj;
        }
      }));
    }

  return (
    <div className='main'>
    <div className="rightnote note-cont">
      <div className="contents">
      {
        mynote.map((obj)=>{
            return (
         <div className={`conts ${isActive === obj.id ? 'cont-active':'cont-inactive'}`} key={obj.id}>
                <div className="con">
                <Content notecontent = {obj.content} noteid={obj.id} onCh={(pullednote) => pullcontent(obj.id,pullednote)}/>
                </div>
             </div>
            )
        })
      }
      </div> 
        </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

**Child**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Content.css';

const Content = (Props,{notecontent,noteid}) => {

  const [note,setnote] = useState(notecontent);

  const changeHandler = (e) =>{
    setnote(e.target.value);
    Props.onCh(note);
  }

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <textarea name="" id={noteid}  defaultValue={notecontent} cols="164" rows="48" contentEditable={true} onChange={(e)=>changeHandler(e)} suppressContentEditableWarning={true}/>
      </div>
  )
}

export default Content;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working if you make these small changes:

```js
// const Content = (Props,{notecontent,noteid}) => { // BEFORE:
const Content = ({onCh, notecontent,noteid}) => { 

  const [note,setnote] = useState(notecontent);

  const changeHandler = (e) =>{
    setnote(e.target.value);
    onCh(note); // <-- Props.onCh() -> onCh()
  }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy this is working. Any idea why this was not working when keeping props.

Comment: Hey @AkashKr.Das. The Component function accepts one argument (object) which contains all the props. In your syntax, you were using 2 arguments (Props and the { destructured } ones).

Answer (score 0):

First change this

`const Content = (Props,{notecontent,noteid}) => {`

to

`const Content = ({onCh,notecontent,noteid}) => {`

After this your typed text will be one character less

This happens because you are using setnote and then passing the note value right after it.

The way react works is that when you have setState calls inside a function the value is only updated when the function has finished execution.
So in this case

```
const changeHandler = (e) =>{
    setnote(e.target.value);
    onCh(note);
    // The value of the note is not set here when you pass it
}
// After this function has finished execution then it is passed
```

There are 2 solutions to this

1. Just pass the `e.target.value` to the `Props.onCh` function

```
const changeHandler = (e) =>{
    setnote(e.target.value);
    onCh(e.target.value);
}
```

2. use `flushSync`

```
import { flushSync } from 'react-dom';

...

const changeHandler = (e) =>{
    flushSync(()=>{
    setnote(e.target.value);
    onCh(note);
    })
}
```

But, I would recommend the first way as flushSync is performance heavy.

Comment: thanks buddy , it worked on changing Props  element.